# Emulate Replacer and Space from JS's JSON.stringify() in PHP with json_encode()?

Tags: php, arrays

In JS you can `stringify` an array with two other arguments (`replacer and space`) which create a new line for each object within the array. This is useful for human readable format when writing to a file.

```
JSON.stringify(array, null, 2);
```

How can I emulate this replacer and space behavior in PHP?

```
json_encode($array, null, 2);
```

Currently, my json_encoded array data writes to a single line, how can I write it to multiple lines in a good format?

```js
//Currently json_decode writes to file like this
[{"test": "test"},{"test": "test"}]

//But I want it to write to the file like this.
[
  {
    "test": "test"
  },
  {
    "test": "test"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the flag `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to the `json_encode` function.

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The output will not be exactly the same as from javascript, but it is much easier to read. For further reading on the JSON constants: https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php